# накладывание текстур на cube three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

хотел бы задать вопрос, как возможно присвоить кубу состоящему из

```
let mats = [
  matBase,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null  
];
let mats1 = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  matBase,
  null  
];
let mats2 = [
  null,
  matBase,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null  
];
let mats3 = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  matBase  
];
```

присвоить по клику на кнопку это:

```
let mats4 = [
  materialal,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null  
];
let mats5 = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  materialal,
  null  
];
let mats6 = [
  null,
  materialal,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null  
];
let mats7 = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  materialal  
];
```

вот основной код добавления текстур на кубы:

```
 const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material4);
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats);
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats1);
const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats2);
const cube4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats3);
scene.add(cube);
scene.add(cube1);
scene.add(cube2);
scene.add(cube3);
scene.add(cube4);
```

и то, что я пытался сделать

```
$('btn11').onclick = function() {
        
        
    const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats4);
    const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats5);
    const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats6);
    const cube4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats7);
    };
```

Comment: Поясняющие картинки могли бы помочь понять - каков требуемый результат.

Comment: ну как, были текстуры одного цвета, а по кнопке должны стать другого

Comment: А почему используется несколько кубов с только одной видимой стороной? Проще использовать несколько квадратов, в формации куба, где каждый (квадрат) имеет свой материал. По-моему, вы сами себе усложняете задачу на ровном месте, используя такой подход.

Comment: так надо для проекта, а сейчас могу ли я попросить вас мне помочь с данной проблемой?

Comment: Тогда надо начать с того, что в `onclick` старые кубы не удаляются из сцены, а заново созданные не добавляются в сцену.

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду, можно ли внутри onclick менять материал, если да, то какая функция может это сделать

Comment: Тогда в onclick будет что-то типа такого: `cube1.material[0] = materialal;`. И так - для каждого куба, где в массиве материалов указывается нужный (через его индекс) и ему присваивается необходимый материал. Общий совет: смотрите справку, исследуйте исходный код официальных примеров. Ну, и добро пожаловать на форум: https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
$('btn11').onclick = function() {

cube1.material[0] = materialal;
    cube2.material[4] = materialal;
    cube3.material[1] = materialal;
    cube4.material[5] = materialal;
}
```